# BioPython "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request" error message

Tags: biopython

I want to retrieve data from Pubmed using biopython.
I have a key word and the target period to collect the data.

```
from Bio import Entrez
from io import StringIO
import csv

# Set email and API key 
Entrez.email = 'helloworld@gmail.com'
Entrez.api_key = 'helloworld'

# Define search terms and time window
search_term = 'cancer'
start_date = '2015/01/01'
end_date = '2015/08/30'

# Define search query
query = f'{search_term}[Title/Abstract] AND ("{start_date}"[Date - Publication] : "{end_date}"[Date - Publication])'

# Search PUBMED using the query
handle = Entrez.esearch(db='pubmed', term=query, retmax=10000)
record = Entrez.read(handle)
id_list = record['IdList']
```

However, the line of handle keeps showing me the error message.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKYkr.png)

How can I solve this issue? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a real API key. When logged in on ncbi - which can quickly be done with a google account for example - you can create an API key here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/account/settings/.

When I executed your script with my API key for Entrez.api_key, I got a correct result (I did not need to also update the email address, key was enough). I checked by adding a `print(len(id_list))` at the end of your script. It gave me 9999 (which might indicate that the search query is still a bit broad).

When entering a wrong API key I also received a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`.

Comment: Glad to hear. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted in order to indicate that this indeed solved your problem.